# AWS - Dynamo Query Partition key List

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to AWS. Can I query the dynamo data on the same table where the Partition key(docType) equals to AA or BB or CC etc? I don't see "OR" or "IN" clauses in keyConditionExpression. Is there any way to achieve this? I'm using node.js  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No.

DDB Query only works for a single partition.  Thus the requirement for a [single partition key value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html).

> You must provide the name of the partition key attribute and a single
> value for that attribute.
>
> Use the KeyConditionExpression parameter to provide a specific value
> for the partition key.

Scan is the only read operation that will work across partitions.  ([optionally at the same time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ParallelScan))

Using scan routinely is a very bad practice. As it reads the entire table, beginning to end, every time. (though it remains subject to DDB 1MB read limit)

Comment: Thank you, Scan is too costly, is there any option to Join the queries?

Comment: sure, you can merge the results client side...